# How to send MySQL id within PHP loop to AJAX PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, variables

I am battling with how to isolate specific MySQL id's when clicked for AJAX call to PHP counter file. Originally I used non-javascript HTLM with echoed PHP to create an array of blocks, each representing a single media file, on a page. When user clicks on block then it goes to a PHP counter file and plays the media file. It is working fine. Running into problems when trying to convert to AJAX/javascript running of the PHP counter file.

The problems appear to be:

1. the proper ID is not registered using the onclick.
2. the ID is not being passed to the Ajax called php file and the counters are not updating.

The javascript in head of main block building file is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>';
```

Hundreds of blocks, each with separate MySQL ID are built and displayed on main page.

ADDITION 040913: The PHP starts with:

```
WHILE ($varX <= $varY) {
mysql_select_db($database_cms_test, $cms_test);
$query = "SELECT * FROM reference WHERE rank=$varRank";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die();
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); ...
```

The Ajax part starts here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function runCounter() {
    var currentID = 222; 
    $.get("counter5.php?id=222"); 
    alert("the current id is " + 222);
} 
</script>

<a title="Media File Name" href "#" onclick= "runCounter();" id="sprytrigger1">
```

The equivalent Ajax code prior to echoing is:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'function runCounter() {';
echo ' var currentID = ';
printf ("%s", $row['id']);  
echo '; $.get("';
echo 'counter5.php?id=';
printf ("%s", $row['id']); 
echo '"); alert("the current id is " + ';
printf ("%s", $row['id']);  
echo ');} </script>';

echo '<a title="';
printf ("%s", $row['song_name']);
echo '" href "#';
echo '" onclick= "runCounter();';
echo '" id="sprytrigger';
echo $varRank;
echo '">';
```

In the counter5.php file, the main id request code is:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

Thank you so much in advance for your advice / suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code...

```
$scr = 'var currentID = ' . $row['id'] .
       '$.get("counter5.php?id='. $row['id'] .'")' .
       'alert("the current id is " + '. $row['id'] .')';
```

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('click', '#btn-id', function(){    
    runCounter();
  })

  function runCounter(){
    <?php echo $scr; ?>
  }
</script>
```

Full code

```
<html>
  <title>Your title</title>
  <head>
    <?php

      // get the value/content of $row variable here...

      $scr = 'var currentID = ' . $row['id'] .
             '$.get("counter5.php?id='. $row['id'] .'")' .
             'alert("the current id is " + '. $row['id'] .')';
    ?>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on('click', '#sprytrigger1', function(){    
        runCounter();
      })

      function runCounter(){
        <?php echo $scr; ?>
      }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <! -- your body here -->
    <a href="#" id="sprytrigger1">Click me!</a>

  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this will help you in some way.

Comment: Hi, when I try this I get an error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ***.php on line 219. I tried to change $results to $result to match my previous MySQL query but received same error.

Comment: make sure that $results is an associative array that goes like this array([0] => array('id'=>1,'name'=>'james'), [1] => arrau('id'=>2,'name'=>'eric'))

Comment: I was wondering if you could give me a bit more info on how to build the associative array for $results. Right now I am just using mysql select to retrieve the data including id to $result and $row.

Comment: I still get the same error on the foreach. I think I am not understanding something about arrays and foreach. I have added an edit above in original post after "Added ADDITION 040913: The PHP starts with:" explaining the While loop everything is in as well as the MySQL query. Really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: I had already tried that. when I do that and "view page source" the code looks right but for some reason when user clicks on a block a seemingly random id is alerted.

Comment: Trying to figure out where to put the script with the latest edit. I tried it in the head as well as echoing within the PHP WHILE loop. Neither seemed to work.

Comment: Thanks for your continuing assistance. But it still does not work. Not sure if this helps but the view source onclick area on the live site using your latest code is as follows: <a title="********"a href="#" onclick= "runCounter();" id="sprytrigger1">

Comment: Hi still not working so I have re-asked the question with some simpler code - please see my other post if you have a moment.

Answer (score -2):

why you use echo if you can just go out of the php and go in again

```
?>your code here<?php
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked?

Comment: because it is within a php loop which cannot be easily exited